# Move <h1> Header above navigation bar

Tags: html, css, header, position

In my program I decided to add a header for the title of the page. The issue is that the new header won't go above the navigation bar. At one point it worked, however; none of the formatting connected. Now that I got the formatting of the text almost right (color is still wrong), the position of it is off again.

This is the short code:

http://jsfiddle.net/edqq8trg/

More of my code:

```
#screen {}

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DAE6F0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

#gradient {
    height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    /* IE 10 */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #81a8cb 0%, #1947D1 100%);

    /* Firefox */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #81a8cb, #1947D1); 

    /* Safari  & Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top, color-stop(0, #1947D1),color-stop(1, #81a8cb)); 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px black;
}

h1.name{
    font-family: Lato, 'Courier Bold', sanserif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    float:left;
    color: "#335CD6";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css" type = "text/css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "formstylesheet.css" type = "text/css">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=80" />
</head>

<div id = "screen">
<body>

<h1 class = "name"> Prog-Assist </h1>

<div id = "header">
    <div id = "gradient">

..................... more code
    </div>
</div> <!-- end header --> 

</div> <!-- end screen-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you added `<div id = "screen">` above the `<body>` tag?

Comment: I will use that to fix the page to not move. Right now if the window is re sized, everything moves around.

Comment: I would add the css you now apply to `<div id = "screen">` to the `<body>` tag...

Comment: Just like this: `body {}`

Comment: Ok but how will that fix my <h1>? I currently have no code yet for my screen id

Comment: Using a `div` tag outside the `body` tag is not recommended at all put it within or do not use it

Comment: Ok I changed that (which didn't change my current issue). I also changed the code back to h .name (where there is a space) but this is the same issue I had before where all the formatting is gone.

Comment: Do not add the space this answer has already been deleted because it was not correct

Comment: oh wow I got -1 for this post. Weird lol

Comment: You have invalid markup. Use a validator first.

Comment: What do you mean invalid markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove

```
float:left;
```

Works just fine now in your Fiddle

Comment: I fixed the h.name to h .name (which makes it go to the top) but removes all formatting. The suggestion you made also didn't change anything for some reason.

Comment: And in the Fiddle I also deleted the `margin-top`

Comment: Oh I see now. I removed the space and added these edits and it works. Thanks! May I ask why these 2 formats do so much to my formatting of the text?

Comment: If you add the space between the `h` and `.name`. The class indentifier part will not be used so all formatting is gone

Comment: Oh I mean't the float and and margin formatting I had

Comment: Ah, that completely changes the position relative to the other tags. But as the `h1` tag is above the `div` tag in your code it will be dislayed above in the browser accordingly without css

Comment: With float-left you place the `h1` left relative to the `div` but as there is no space it will be placed inside

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/edqq8trg/3/

Remove the float left from the H1.

```
h1.name{

    font-family: Lato, 'Courier Bold', sanserif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 30px;

    color: "#335CD6";
    margin-top: 0;
}
```